# How to better this XML?

Tags: xml

I have a XML which should be well-form and valid. However, the visual studio alert me that it has some thing missing..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <tagartSite>
        <site>123123123132</site>
        <ip>123123123132</ip>
    </tagartSite>
    <login>
        <Name>123123123</Name>
        <password>123123123123</password>
    </login>
    <log>
        <path>123123123132</path>
    </log>
</config>
```

Alert:

> Message   7   Could not find schema information for the element 'path'.

So, how to fix it? Will it affect my program?

Comment: There appears to be an XML schema that Visual Studio applies to this XML. You will need to look there.

Comment: The name of the schema file might end in `.xsd`, so you could search the Visual Studio folder for this extension.  Or, just Google around for where to find it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So, i need to create 2 files which one for xml and another for the xsd, then link the xml and xsd together?